# I am trying to run a program which I have cloned from GitHub and followed every step that they told but I am having this problem running it in CMD

Tags: python, github, cmd

```
F:\Hacking\GitHub\sherlock>python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

Answer (score 0):

You provided limited information

1. First off check if you have installed python: I suggest using Anaconda. It's quite straightforward.
2. After that create a conda (Anaconda) environment (imagine it as a space that you can have different versions of packages- Python packages tend to be very dependent on the version of related packages, conda usually check the compatibility of them when you are installing them)
3. Using pip and conda together can be tricky. I suggest first install the main packages then go for more specialized one, maybe using pip
4. Try to have an issue on the github page of the project. If the package is popular or fresh, they usually respond fast.